# Second example in §8.3.2/3 (N4140)

Tags: c++, reference, c++14

This is the second example in §8.3.2/3

```
struct link {
    link* next;
};
link* first;
void h(link*& p) { // p is a reference to pointer
    p->next = first;
    first = p;
    p = 0;
}
void k() {
    link* q = new link;
    h(q);
}
```

Now, when I insert the 4 lines of code below, at the end of the previous snippet, the code doesn't compile ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eca761ae9bbaf585)). I'd like to know why it doesn't.

```
int x = 10;
int* p = &x;
int*& rx = p;
rx = 0;
```

Comment: it does not compile because you put it in global scope - only declarations can go there. Put it all inside function (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7000d8eea730a29)

Comment: When asking question about build errors, always include the actual errors (complete and unedited) in the question itself. External links can go dead.

Comment: You'll get exactly the same error *without* the code from the example. Why you concluded that the example code is relevant is a mystery. If you're a complete beginner, don't try to learn C++ programming from the standard. It's not a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform assignments in global scope. This has nothing to do with references per se:

`p = nullptr;` will fail to compile too. (Don't use 0 for the null pointer.)

Comment: Not only assignments. *All* statements will fail to compile if put in the global scope.

Comment: Of course you're correct, but then we get into deep water thinking about what exactly the construct `int x = 10;` is.